# Type alias for channel in Go works strange

Tags: go, compiler-errors, alias, channel

I want to organize communication between two functions via channels. The callee can only send data to the channel while the caller will wait for it in the `select`. And I want to show this restriction in the callee signature. Another thing that I want is working with type aliases for channels. For example, instead of having `chan string` I want to work with `MsgChan` defined as `type MsgChan chan string`. And I faced with the problem - the code below won't compile if uncomment line `test1(make(Ch))`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Ch chan int
type ChIn chan<- int

func test1(in ChIn) {
    fmt.Println(in)
}

func test2(in chan<- int) {
    fmt.Println(in)
}

func main() {
    //test1(make(Ch))
    test1(make(chan int))
    test2(make(Ch))
    test2(make(ChIn))
}
```

I don't understand why I can't use such approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test1()` has one parameter of type `ChIn`. This is a named type. You want to pass a value of type `Ch` which is a bidirectional channel type, and is also a named type.

So in order for this to compile, a value of `Ch` should be assignable to type `ChIn`. This is not allowed by the language specification.

Quoting [**Assignability**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) (highlighted the one that applies here):

> A value `x` is assignable to a [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") in any of these cases:
>
> - `x`'s type is identical to `T`.
> - `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical [underlying types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a named type.
> - `T` is an interface type and `x` [implements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) `T`.
> - **`x` is a bidirectional channel value, `T` is a channel type, `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical element types, and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a named type.**
> - `x` is the predeclared identifier `nil` and `T` is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type.
> - `x` is an untyped [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) representable by a value of type `T`.

You can make it work if you try to pass a value of unnamed type but having the same underlying type, which can be achieved by using a type conversion, e.g.:

```
test1((chan int)(make(Ch)))
```

But the above conversion would defeat the purpose of having the named `Ch` type (as you have to repeat its type literal in order to convert it to an unnamed type just so you can pass it to `test1()`).

What you should do is don't hide that the type is a channel (don't include `chan` in the type literal of the type declaration), only create a new type for the element type of the channel, e.g.:

```
type Msg int

func test(in chan<- Msg) {
    fmt.Println(in)
}

func main() {
    test(make(chan Msg))
    test(make(chan<- Msg))

    ch := make(chan Msg)
    chIn := (chan<- Msg)(ch)
    test(chIn)
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/aISchHqG0k).

Comment: Great! The spec looks like it's exactly my case! However, I've ended up with using named types for channel's val-type but not the entire channel.

Comment: @IvanVelichko Exactly what you should do, as detailed in the edited answer.